# summarize(&group by) by subgroup in each group

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

all, I try to get the percentage of nationality in the group of people who like apples and in the group of people who do not like apples (Apple==1 if the person likes it, and Apple==0 if not). I use this code but the percentage is not what I want:

```
sample %>%
group_by(Apple,Country) %>%
dplyr::summarise(count=n())%>%
mutate(pct_gender=count/sum(count))
```

What I get from this code the percentage of nationality+apple among all observations. (for example, among all 31 observations, 18 people like Apple. Among 18 people who like apple, 7 are from France. So I want to get 7/18=38.8%, but the result I got is 7/31=22.6%)

Here is the data I used:

```
structure(list(id = 1:30, Country = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", 
"UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France"), Apple = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Banana = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Orange = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Jackfruit = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -30L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Would appreciate if anyone can let me know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get ratio for likes and dislikes, we can first `group_by` `Country` and `Apple`, count the number of rows in each group, `spread` it to wide format and then calculate the ratio.

```
sample %>%
  group_by(Country, Apple) %>%
  summarise(perc = n()) %>%
  mutate(Apple = c("dislike", "like")[Apple + 1])  %>%
  tidyr::spread(Apple, perc, fill = 0) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(dislike, like), ~./sum(.))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Country dislike  like
#  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 France    0     0.353
#2 Germany   0.308 0.118
#3 UK        0.462 0.235
#4 USA       0.231 0.294
```

---

In base R, it is simpler with `table`

```
dat <-table(sample$Country, sample$Apple)
t(t(dat)/colSums(dat))


#                  0         1
#  France  0.0000000 0.3529412
#  Germany 0.3076923 0.1176471
#  UK      0.4615385 0.2352941
#  USA     0.2307692 0.2941176
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, but I got an error msg: "Error in count(., Country) : object 'Country' not found"

Comment: @iceylovedata I am using the `sample` data you provided, works fine for me. Are you using the same data? Do you have column `Country` in it?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same data. Country is a column.

Comment: @iceylovedata okay  I think it must be an issue that `count` is being masked from some other package. You could specify `dplyr::count` explicitly. Can you also try the updated code? I think that is what you were asking getting likes and dislikes separately for "Apple".

Comment: Hi, Ronak, thank you very much! That's exactly what I want.

Comment: And you are right, I think because I library both "dplyr" and "plyr", so I need to put dplyr::summarize instead of summarize. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ronak Shah, this is easier in base than with any other package:

Use `table` (as Ronak suggested), but use **also** `prop.table`:

```
prop.table(table(df$Country, df$Apple), margin = 2)
```

Which produces:

```
                  0         1
  France  0.0000000 0.3529412
  Germany 0.3076923 0.1176471
  UK      0.4615385 0.2352941
  USA     0.2307692 0.2941176
```

Notice that you shouldn't expect 38.8% for France - Like (as in your toy data there's only 6 frech people who liked apple among 17 people overall apple likers).